# Let p and q be primes where p < q and q not ≡ 1 mod p. Then any group G of size pq is cyclic.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let p and q be primes where p < q and q not ≡ 1 mod p. Then any group of size pq is cyclic.

The proof I read says it is sufficient to prove there is an element in G has order pq. I am confused why this is sufficient.

Comment: If an element has order $pq$ then the subgroup it generates is the entire group so...

Answer (score 0):

If $x$ is an element of order $pq$ then there are $pq$ different powers of $x$, from $x^0$ (the identity) to $x^{pq-1}$.  But that's the order of the whole group, so all members of the group are powers of $x$, i.e. the group is cyclic.